# Using key value in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, key-value

I'm new to C++, previous experience with java. How can I implement a key - value structure like in a java hashmap.

I want the structure to map `float` to my defined class `matrix`.

How can I declare the structure, add to it, get from it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The default floating point type in C++ is `double`. E.g. `3.14` is of type `double`. Why are you using `float`.

Comment: I did not know that, I don't mind using a double

Comment: @Clay: I did not downvote you, but please consider doing a little bit of Google research before you ask. "c++ equivalent of java hashmap" immediately reveals the existence of std::map.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I did google, but I wasnt finding what I was looking for. Within a minute of using SO I found the answer. I don't think there is anything wrong with what I did.

Comment: @Clay: it often helps to mention that you already tried Google, if only to keep (sometimes unfair?) downvoters away.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I mistakenly thought  my 1.3k rep would vouch for my google search.

Comment: Hey, I just found this question by Googling "c++ key and value" :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use standard container `std::map<float, matrix>` defined in header `<map>` Or you can use `std::unordered_map<float, matrix>` defined in header `<unordered_map>`

EDIT: An example of using `std::map`

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::map<float, float> angleDict;

   for ( float n = 0.1f; n < 10.0f; n++ ) angleDict[n] = 10.0f - n;

   for ( auto p : angleDict ) std::cout << "( " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " )" << std::endl;
}
```